# DB2 SQL Query Filtering rows based on multiple fields

Tags: db2

I need to write a query based on the following conditions:

Within one table, the following condition must be met:

table name:  DLS_RBM_RBI
columns within the table

- RBM_3_CD must be blank
- If RBM_3_CD is blank, then RBM_2_CD must be 1
- If RBM_3_CD is blank and RBM_2_CD is blank, then RBM_1_CD must be 1

How would these conditions be coded in a SQL statement?  In an IF within a where clause or case in a select?

I tried using a where clause with these conditions.

```
 AND (D.RBM_3_CD = '') 
        OR (D.RBM_3_CD = '' AND D.RBM_2_CD = '1') 
        OR (D.RBM_3_CD = '' AND RBM_2_CD = '' AND RBM_1_CD = '1')
```

Comment: Both work as long as you can describe it. The statement gets translated into some execution plan anyway. You could use a tool to show that plan and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement
`AND (D.RBM_3_CD = ' ')`

negates the need for the second and third.  There's no way for the first statement to false while the second or third are true.

try this instead

```
where D.RBM_3_CD = ' '
   and ( (D.RBM_3_CD = '' AND D.RBM_2_CD = '1')
        or (D.RBM_3_CD = '' AND RBM_2_CD = '' AND RBM_1_CD = '1') 
       )
```